# Creating a master template in powerpoint that can't be changed

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I need to create a master template in powerpoint but do not have kuch experience in powerpoint and need to achieve the following.

1) Need to create a master template as a standard template that all members of a organization can use.

2) This template can't be edited, only the content of this template can be edited. Eg. Fonts, animations and images, basically the background should remain the same

Is this possible to do in powerpoint and how can I achieve this?

Any help will be highly valued.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to prevent users from editing the master via an add-in IF you could be sure that they would only work with the presentations on computers that had the add-in installed.

Otherwise, not possible.